# Magento 2 - can't enable production mode. Shows Command returned non-zero exit code

Tags: magento2, compilation

I am trying to set Magento 2 website in production mode. However unable to set. It gives me below error.

> Command returned non-zero exit code:
>   /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php -f /var/www/vhosts/sitename/httpdocs/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US

server's memory_limit is set to **2G**. Magento version is 2.1.

Anybody could say what's wrong here while setting store in production mode?

Comment: The command you're running is to the command the change the mode. It's the command that deploys the static content. Could you try `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` ?

Comment: Yes, i am using bin/magento deploy:mode:set production command to set in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using these commands.

Run this commands

1. sudo php bin/magento maintenance:disable
2. clear cache
3. sudo chmod 777 var* -R
4. sudo chmod 777 pub* -R